# vertical align img within master div

Tags: css

I've seen many questions like this, but i can't seem to find the answer:

i have a picture with a MAX file size of 128 by 128 px
some are that size, but i also have 128*90, 60*60, 58*78 etc.

now i want to vertical align it within a div; ive seen examples with top 50% and margin -25px if it is a img with a height of 50px, but i don't know the heigth in advance...

grtz,
michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery to get the height of the images, then set margin: -height/2

or ..

you can set the image as the background of the containing div, something like:

```
 background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Comment: i load the image dynamicly, if i check the width after that, it gives me 0 (zero)

Comment: use "background", not "background-image"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
    div#parent {
    background:blue;
    height:500px;
    }

    div#child {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    zoom:1; /* haslayout */
    }

    div#ie-helper {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    top:-25%;
    zoom:1; /* haslayout */
    }
</style>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"><div id="ie-helper">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6f6f22658c768b1162200786e3407890?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to center something vertically in HTML/CSS so far is to use a table cell - that's the only element that supports vertical centering in ALL browsers.

For a picture however I would simply set it as the background picture of the DIV, because you can center background pictures vertically.

Comment: you can rely on positioning and percentages, which is the most consistent method.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work in old ie's but keep you code clean and tableless and use table features with

```
.foo { 
  height: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
<div class="foo">hi</div>
```